# What is the difference between ST_BuildArea and ST_Polygonize?

Tags: postgis

The two functions [`ST_BuildArea`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_BuildArea.html) and [`ST_Polygonize`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Polygonize.html) both take lines and produce polygons.

It seems that `ST_BuildArea` assumes that inner rings represent holes and omits them from the result, while `ST_Polygonize` includes them in the result.  And the mechanics of using the functions are a bit different: `ST_Polygonize` is an aggregate, while `ST_BuildArea` requires that you bundle up the inputs yourself using `ST_Collect`.

Beyond this, are there any differences between the two functions?

Comment: Perhaps these presentation slides might help: [http://2010.foss4g.org/presentations/3369.pdf](http://2010.foss4g.org/presentations/3369.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, but could be a starting point for someone looking for more details.

`ST_Polygonize` (in the form of `polygonize_garray`) and `ST_BuildArea` are defined in the source code (mirror) at https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-trunk/postgis/lwgeom_geos.c.

They both eventually call `GEOSPolygonize`, which is defined in [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/), which is a C/C++ port of the [Java Topology Suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTS_Topology_Suite).

And from the docs -

> ST_Polygonize - Creates a GeometryCollection containing possible polygons formed from the constituent linework of a set of geometries. https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Polygonize.html
>
> ST_BuildArea - Creates an areal geometry formed by the constituent linework of given geometry. The return type can be a Polygon or MultiPolygon, depending on input. If the input lineworks do not form polygons NULL is returned. The inputs can be LINESTRINGS, MULTILINESTRINGS, POLYGONS, MULTIPOLYGONS, and GeometryCollections.
> This function will assume all inner geometries represent holes. http://postgis.net/docs/ST_BuildArea.html